# Last non-merge commit author for a list of branches

Tags: git

I'm working on cleaning up the repo. I ran the following to get the list of merge branches (most likely stale; left behind).

```
git branch -r --merged origin/release/mayor.minor.patch > merged
```

How can I enhance that query to also get the name of the author of the last commit for each branch (excluding merge commits).

The idea is to then send the list to the Team and ask for help cleaning up.

Comment: How can I apply (or append) `git log -1 --no-merges --pretty=format:'%an'` to it?

Comment: Branches don't have authors; only commits have authors. A branch name is simply a name for the *last* commit that is part of the branch. Your `git log -1` is a way to start at the last commit and keep working backwards, one commit at a time, until finding a non-merge commit. So first, get the name of the branch; then pass that branch name to `git log -1 ...` to select a commit and print the name of the commit's author. Be aware that this commit might be in multiple branches.

Comment: I added the clarification to the description about commit author. Thnx. @torek

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by using

```
for branch in `git branch -r --merged origin/release/major.minor.fix`;do echo -e `git log -1 --no-merges --pretty=format:'%an' $branch` \\t$branch; done | sort -r
```

Answer (score 0):

I had good results with this:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(authorname) %09 %(refname)' --merged origin > merged
```

Comment: It's not excluding the merge commits